# Django + Apache Internal Server Error: Permission denied

Tags: django, git, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using Django 1.6 and Apache for my website, at first the server worked well, I could successfully go to my web pages, but just after I run:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

in my /var/www/html/mysite repository, it showed Internal Server Error in the browser and I got this in the error log:

```
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=15479): Create interpreter 'www.XXX.XXX|'.
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=15479): Adding '/var/www/html/mysite' to path.
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=15479): Adding '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11] mod_wsgi (pid=15479): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     self.load_middleware()
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 44, in load_middleware
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     self._configure_logging()
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11]     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/debug.log'
```

I saw it was "Permission denied", so I've run:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data mysite
```

And also:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 mysite
```

But it is still not working, I even changed the persmission to `777` for the whole `html` directory but it was no use.
I don't understand why there came out an permission error, is there anything related to the git command that I run?

PS : I didn't mentioned at all the `/debug.log` in my settings.py, I wrote:

```
  LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': True,
  'handlers': {
    'file': {
      'level': 'DEBUG',
      'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
      'filename': 'debug.log',
    },
  },
  'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
      'handlers': ['file'],
      'level': 'DEBUG',
      'propagate': True,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: What's the `LOG_ROOT` in the settings look like? I feel like your app is trying to access the absolute directory `/debug.log` which is the base directory in your linux box. If your settings is tracked in the repo, try to `git blame settings.py` and see the changes.

Comment: well it seems that I didn't add the `LOG_ROOT` in the settings.py

Comment: Don't log to a separate file. Log to the console handler and have mod_wsgi capture the Django log output and send it into the Apache error log. That is better way of doing it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736077/log-all-requests-to-file-django In short the problem is you can't use a relative path for log as default current working directory could be anything and if root directory will not be writable.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'd rather use the absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your settings.py in the file, in the section that controls logging.

```
[Thu Jun 09 16:28:32 2016] [error] [client 10.192.76.11] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/debug.log'
```

While you can certainly write to /debug.log with proper permissions, it's an unlikely location. Please choose a more appropriate one. You can do that by changing this line:

```
'filename': 'debug.log',
```

in your logging setup. Be sure to give a full path eg /tmp/debug.log or /var/log/httpd/debug.log

If you really want to write to that file do

```
 sudo touch /debug.log
 sudo chown www-data:www-data /debug.log
```

and reload mod wsgi