# How can I log the requests that my django server makes?

Tags: django

I know that I can use logging to log all the requests that my django server gets. However I would like to log the requests along with headers and body that my django server makes to other servers. How can I access this info?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

What type of logs do you really want?

1 - in development mode, you can get the request as .txt using: `python manage.py runserver > logs.txt` - source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910505/save-django-request-logs-in-a-file)

2 - The Apache2 webserver provides two important logs: **error.log** or **access.log**. If you are using debian/ubuntu, you can get it in?

> /var/log/apache2/error.log or access.log

Comment: I want to log the requests that my server makes. Not the requests that my server receives.

Comment: 2 things again: 1 - request by django url requests: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737733/send-http-request-using-django-and-get-results [/link], 2 - get all requests by **server**  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736077/log-all-requests-to-file-django [/link] this can you help you